# How to merge objects in JS only when they are defined?

Tags: javascript, merge, javascript-objects

I am learning JS and currently I need to 4 objects to merge with each other, but I have to make sure that in the result I will not have "undefined" inside the result object.

Currently, I implemented it like this:

```
  let result = {};
  result = Object.assign(result, first);
  if (second) result = Object.assign(result, second);
  if (third) result = Object.assign(result, third);
  if (fourth) result = Object.assign(result, fourth);
  return result;
```

But, I believe there must be a cleaner solution for this task. 
Are there any?

Comment: What do you mean by "*have some of the `undefined` inside the result object*"? Only a property can be undefined, the result is always an object.

Comment: How about setting everything to some value at  the start.

Comment: I had undefined because of this:  let result = {...first,second,third,fourth};

Comment: "I need to 4 objects with each other" -- the verb seems to be missing. What do you need to do with each other?

Comment: my bad, "merge"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) ignores `undefined` argument values. You can simplify to

```
return Object.assign({}, first, second, third, fourth);
```

Comment: Seems like it ignores all the _falsy values_.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This one with varargs is good. I had undefined values when I did the following : let result = {...first,second,third,fourth};

Comment: @dvelopp If you intended to use the experimental object spread syntax, it would need to be `{...first, ...second, ...third, ...fourth}`, otherwise it's a shorthand for creating a property named `second` (with the value of the `second` variable, which may be an object or `undefined`).

Comment: i think it should be {...first,...second,...third,...fourth} maybe that's why you got undefined values? Bergi was faster in the explanation

Comment: Great! It explains why I had undefined. I like the option with "...first, ...second, ...third, ...fourth". Any difference with Object.assign({}, first, second, third, fourth)?

Comment: @dvelopp Spread syntax is likely to be open-coded by the compiler, `Object.assign()` will perform a function call. But the results should be identical.